# Perl get XML node value using XML:LibXML

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I am trying to print out content of nodes to do further process. Wanted to print `x_id="123"` and node `"a"` content. I am using XML:LibXML parser. Any suggestion? I am very new to this file parser.

Example XML:

```
<header>
    <id x_id="123">                            
        <a>testing</a>
        <b></b>
    </id>
</header>
```

Current not working code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $template = "xx.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($template);
my($object) = $doc->findnodes("/header/id/");
print $doc->findvalue("/header/id/x_id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code snippet for demo

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $file = 'test.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);

foreach my $node ($dom->findnodes('//idset')) {
    say 'NodeID: ', $node->{id};
    say 'ItemA: ', $node->findvalue('./a');
    say 'ItemB: ', $node->findvalue('./b');
    say '';
}
```

Content of input file `text.xml`

```
<header>
    <idset id="100">                            
        <a>item_a</a>
        <b>item_b</b>
    </idset>
    <idset id="101">                            
        <a>item_c</a>
        <b>item_d</b>
    </idset>
</header>
```

Output

```
NodeID: 100
ItemA: item_a
ItemB: item_b

NodeID: 101
ItemA: item_c
ItemB: item_d
```

Comment: Hi Polar Bear, tried on your code but shows "Not a HASH reference at line 12"

Comment: Line 12 is : say 'NodeID: ', $node->{id};

Comment: @toolic -- OP's data is not good example for demonstration. Only one node with confusing identification `id` and `x_id`, tags are not complaint with [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) specification.

Comment: @Blurman -- What `OS`, `perl` and `XML::LibXML` versions are you using? In my case it is `Windows 10`, `Strawberry perl v5.30.2`, `XML::LibXML 2.0203`.

Comment: I am looking through the sample from [https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/basics.html] and understand how to call out the child node (title, director in the first example in the link), but no idea to call the "id" in the "movie" element.

Comment: @Blurman -- I am not specialist on `XML::LibXML` but `say 'ID:       ', $movie->{id};` produces output with expected id.

Comment: @Polar Bear, it shows Not a HASH reference for me when calling element node. Let me open new tread to ask this. Thanks